# Error Occuring while including html file using ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I got following error while including html file using `ng-include`.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/algo/Dnyaneshwar/Angular/TestProject/views/header1.html. 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: 
http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: This is a CORS issue.  There's quite a lot of information out there on how to address it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cause of Issue**
This error is happening because you are just trying to open your html documents directly from the browser. Since you are using either file:// or C:/, thats why the error is saying that they are not http:// or https:// .
Don't try to run it through folder directly.

**How to fix it**
You need to access your code through a webserver and access it on localhost. If you have eclipse or apache setup, use it to access your files. Some IDE's like intellij,eclipse have built in web servers.

If you have node setup then Just run `npm install http-server -g` and you will be able to use it in terminal like http-server C:\path\to\app

### See Also

- [“Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.” error when
  loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: I used eclipse IDE and apache tomcat 7 to run my web project and it works